# How to run a single test file multiple times in qt creator

Tags: qt, googletest

I want to run a single gtest file multiple times in qt creator.

```
--gtest_filter="*Mytest*" --gtest_shuffle=1 --gtest_random_seed=20 --gtest_repeat=50 --gtest_break_on_failure
```

I used this filter doesn't seem to be working

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working" is a useless diagnostic. How is the commandline argument string you pasted involved "in running tests in qt creator"? Show us a setup (or [mre]) so that anyone can recreate your problem on their end and propose a valid fix instead of guessing.

Comment: I used this argument inside project->run settings->command line argument.

Comment: Does it work if you run it from the commandline? If not the problem is not in Qt creator but in your "gtest file".